# boost and flyback converter

Tags: power-electronics, boost, ltspice

I am currently analysing this circuit [image: Fig 1 : Circuit 1]

But I ran into some problem since the boost component standalone raises the voltage to 40v the flyback is suppose to bring up the voltage to a further 540v right ?

But from my analysis I found that the boost acts like a buck 
[image: Fig 2 : VT graph of boost part of the circuit]

And the total voltage output now becomes

140v, which is far from the expected 540 v so could someone help me explain why this occurs ? Thank You :)

Comment: Just a hunch: The C1/1uF in parallel with the primary of the transformer could be limiting the transients severely, and you need those to produce the high voltage on the secondary.

Comment: After removing the C1 I did remove some loss but the voltage increase until 150v only, thanks for the reply

Comment: I suggest you take your problem apart.  You have checked that the first stage does what it's supposed to?  How about the second stage?  If you simulate your second stage with a 40V voltage source (instead of your boost circuit) do you get what you expect?  Hint: look at the current through R1.